# using markdown and latex in email

Tags: email, latex, markdown

Is there a fast and easy way to use both,

- Markdown
- LaTeX

in emails? I love the way to format questions the way it is supported on StackExchange.
I want to use both, because I love the simple way to format markdown for layout but I need Latex' math mode  for writing formulas.
Best I could imagine would be an editor (don't need to be part of the mail client), which parses the LaTeX and outputs picture and parses the markdown and outputs html (including the latex-pictures). Afterwards I just need to send the html email. If you recommend a standalone editor, could you also explain how to set `Content-Type: multipart/alternative;` in Apple Mail?

Answer (score 3):

### [markdown-here](http://markdown-here.com/)

[markdown-here](http://markdown-here.com/) works quite well (and it's open source).
See also [this question on tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118246/how-to-send-an-email-with-latex)